# Is true that for any two natural number $m$, $n$: $\ m-n+1\leq \varphi(n)\varphi(m)$?

Tags: number-theory

Is true that for any two natural number $m$, $n$: $\ m-n+1\leq \varphi(n)\varphi(m)$? 
Such that $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler's totient function.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: What about $n=1?$ This would give the (mostly) wrong $m\le\varphi(m)!$

Comment: Take $m=15, n=2$.

Comment: As you can see from the above two comments, your "any" is ambiguous. You should clarify whether you are asking about the existence of such numbers (the answer in that case would be yes) or about whether this inequality holds for all naturaly numbers $m$, $n$ (the answer in that case would be no).

Comment: @joriki I would interpret "any" as universal quantification i.e. "forall" - so I'd say no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimate $m-n+1\le \phi(n)\phi(m)$ does not hold for all $n,m\ge 1$.
It cannot hold for all $m\ge 1$ even if we fix $n$. For convenience let 
$n=1$. Then
$$
m\le \phi(m)
$$
does not hold for any $m\ge 2$. For
$n=2$ we obtain
$$
m\le \phi(2)\phi(m)+1=\phi(m)+1,
$$
which does not hold for, say, $m=2^k$ with $k\ge 2$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true for all $m, n$ as shown in the comments. I can show that it's true for all prime choices of $m$ and $n$. That give you $\pi(N)^2 - \pi(N)$ solutions with $m,n$ less than or equal to $N$ at least! Suppose $m$ and $n$ are prime:
$$m - n + 1 \leq (n - 1)(m - 1) = nm - n - m + 1$$
Simplifying the inequality gives:
$$m \leq m(n - 1)$$
And is true for all $m$ if $n \geq 2$. Of course, proving that it's true for all prime pairs doesn't exhaust the solution space very much.

Another trivial thing to observe is that any pair where $m < n$ is a solution since $\varphi$ is non-negative.